# Angular2 http authenticate

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to authenticate via Angular2 Typescript and it is not working because it is asking me at the browser. Whats wrong with my code?

```
callrest(){
  let url="/edison";
  return this.http.post(url, this.getPutHeaders()).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
               data => console.log(data),
               err => console.log(err)
            );;
}



private getPutHeaders(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' +
      btoa('user:pw'));
    return new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers

    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: authenticate via angular means ? angular provides guards for you to check if the user is authorized to log in or not . so are you asking about angular guards?

Comment: I need a http auth within Angular with Typescript. See my code above please. The basic auth is not working and the dialog is displaying. Even I setted the header auth

Comment: you take at look at this repo i have used angular guards for the same , it might serve as a good starting point for auth https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts/tree/master/src/app/guards  take a look at it and give me a poke after that hope that will help